# I got error installing mongodb on my remote ubuntu 18?

Tags: apt, mongodb

Reading this article
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

I try to install mongodb on my remote ubuntu 18 I got error :

```
root@nsn-do-lamp:~# wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-6.0.asc | sudo apt-key add -
OK
root@nsn-do-lamp:~# 
root@nsn-do-lamp:~# wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-6.0.asc | sudo apt-key add -
OK
root@nsn-do-lamp:~# echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/6.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-6.0.list
deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/6.0 multiverse
root@nsn-do-lamp:~# sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org
root@nsn-do-lamp:~# sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                                                          
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                                                               
Hit:4 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                                                                   
Hit:5 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_14.x bionic InRelease                                                                                                               
Hit:6 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                                           
Hit:7 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                          
Hit:8 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease  
Ign:9 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/6.0 InRelease
Get:10 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/6.0 Release [4412 B]
Get:11 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/6.0 Release.gpg [801 B]
Get:12 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/6.0/multiverse amd64 Packages [6644 B]
Get:13 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/6.0/multiverse arm64 Packages [5562 B]
Fetched 17.4 kB in 2s (9957 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
root@nsn-do-lamp:~# sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-org : Depends: mongodb-org-database but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

...
root@nsn-do-lamp:~# uname -a
Linux nsn-do-lamp 4.15.0-191-generic #202-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 4 01:49:29 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@nsn-do-lamp:~# lsb_release -d; uname -r; uname -i
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
4.15.0-191-generic
x86_64
```

Why I got the error and how can it be fixed ?

**UPDATED :**

I tried to fix this problem with proposed methods and got error  :

```
sudo apt-get install -y  mongodb-org-mongos  mongodb-org-server   mongodb-org   mongodb-org-database
...
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

     mongodb-org-mongos : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.29) but 2.27-3ubuntu1.6 is to be installed
                          Depends: libgcc-s1 (>= 4.2) but it is not installable
     mongodb-org-server : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.29) but 2.27-3ubuntu1.6 is to be installed
                          Depends: libgcc-s1 (>= 4.2) but it is not installable
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Looks like I have old ubuntu 18 and that eaised this error

I suppose that it could be salved with option “Install a specific release of MongoDB.”

But I am not sure which version(how can I find it) of MongoDB have I to install  ?

Thanks!

Comment: You only need one architecture for installation.  You are running just a 64bit system so all you need is just `[arch=amd64]`

Comment: Copuld you please detalize it. I copypasted line with "echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] ..." Have I to edit it firstly before running on server ?

Comment: I got it working in Ubuntu 18.04, see my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Installing MongoDB 6.0 into Ubuntu 18.04 LTS:

First, remove MongoDB from previous if installed:

```
sudo apt remove --autoremove mongodb-org
```

Remove any mongodb repo list files:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb*.list
sudo apt update
```

Add the new key:

```
wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-6.0.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

Add the new repo:

```
echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/6.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-6.0.list
```

Update the system for the new repo:

```
sudo apt update
```

Install MongoDB 6.0:

```
sudo apt install mongodb-org
```

Enable and start the mongod server service:

```
systemctl enable mongod.service
systemctl start mongod.service
```

Check that the service has started:

```
terrance@ubuntu-virtualbox:~$ systemctl status mongod.service 
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2022-08-21 09:08:43 MDT; 9min ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
 Main PID: 1015 (mongod)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mongod.service
           └─1015 /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf

Aug 21 09:08:43 ubuntu-virtualbox systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Aug 21 09:09:28 ubuntu-virtualbox systemd[1]: mongod.service: Current command vanished from the unit file, execution of the command list won't be resumed.
```

Check MongoDB server version:

```
terrance@ubuntu-virtualbox:~$ mongos --version
mongos version v6.0.1
Build Info: {
    "version": "6.0.1",
    "gitVersion": "32f0f9c88dc44a2c8073a5bd47cf779d4bfdee6b",
    "openSSLVersion": "OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018",
    "modules": [],
    "allocator": "tcmalloc",
    "environment": {
        "distmod": "ubuntu1804",
        "distarch": "x86_64",
        "target_arch": "x86_64"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to reload your sources between:

```
root@nsn-do-lamp:~# echo "deb ...
```

and

```
root@nsn-do-lamp:~# sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

as explained at step 2. Do

```
sudo apt update
```

and then it will install. Mind that `gnupg` needs to be installed too.

---

> root@nsn-do-lamp:~# sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org"

This is BAD: never use a root login with sudo. So drop the sudo if you want to use root. But I would suggest not to use root and use the admin user and sudo.

Comment: Please look at UPDATED INFO

Answer (score 1):

Monogodb was installed but you have missing dependencies, that's it,

Every time you encounter this whether using wget or package install,

add this command

```
apt-get install --fix-missing ; sudo apt-get install -f
```